# Brew warning: dependency was built with a different C++ standard library

Tags: c++, boost, homebrew, bioinformatics, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded my homebrew-installed packages, and after "Trinity-rnaseq" upgraded from 2.4 to 2.5, I received the following warning"

`Warning: homebrew/science/trinity dependency boost was built with a different C++ standard library (libc++ from clang). This may cause problems at runtime.`

I'm somewhat new to homebrew as a whole, and was wondering what the safest way to fix the boost dependency would be, if it is even necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rebuild boost and then anything that depends on boost and then your project. And yes, if any of that uses boost as part of a public interface it can easily be a problem.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated!